# Java: Connect to Database and return query result

Tags: java, database-connection, return-value

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database in Java, execute a query, and return the result to the calling script.

`class DB
    {
            public DB() {}`

```
        public Connection dbConnect(String db_connect_string)
        {
                try
                {
                        Class.forName(
                          "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");

                        Connection conn =
                          DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string);

                        System.out.println("connected");
                        return conn;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return true;
                }
        }
};
class getConnection
{
        public void main(String[] args)
        {
                DB db = new DB();
                Connection conn=db.dbConnect(
          "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://host:1433;User=user;Password=Pwd");
        }

}
return true;
```

As far as I can tell this tells me the connection is fine, but my Java is less than limited. Can someone tell me if this part is fine and add a simple select statement to it, which is then passed back via return?

Comment: I recommend to use either JPA or (pooled) DataSources and JdbcTemplate from Spring (should be useable even if you don't use Spring otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to do some reading up.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Comment: StackOverflow is brilliant, but its no substitute for reading books (or doing a google search)  ;-)

Comment: I can sense that these days StackOverflow is rather being overwhelmed by questions which can simply be answered by a single RTFM!

Comment: StackOverflow used to be quite newbie-friendly. If my question is so easy to answer why doesn't one of you?

Comment: @Marius - That is the best answer one can give! We can only show you the way, but not walk you.

Answer (score 2):

May be you should brush up how to use [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)

```
public Statement getStatement()
{

      return conObject.createStatement();

}
```